# DRY Jquery Select drop down show div

Tags: jquery, function, loops

Ok I have 4 to 5 select dropdowns and they do a simple job of showing a different div's each. The code is getting repeated several times is there any way I can make a function and call it on different Div's. Thanks for your help.

```js
        $('.select--one').change(function() {
            var var1 = $('.select--one option:selected').val();
            $('.one').removeClass('active');
            $('#' + var1 ).addClass('active');
        });

        $('.select--two').change(function() {
            var var2 = $('.select--two option:selected').val();
            $('.two').removeClass('active');
            $('#' + var2 ).addClass('active');
        });

        $('.select--three').change(function() {
            var var3 = $('.select--three option:selected').val();
            $('.three').removeClass('active');
            $('#' + var3 ).addClass('active');
        });
```

```css
div {
    display: none;
}
div.active{
    display: block;
    margin:40px 40px 0 0;
    background : gold;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;
    float:left;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Show Selected Div </p> 

<select class="select--one">
   <option value="div-1">Div 1</option>
   <option value="div-2">Div 2</option>
   <option value="div-3">Div 3</option>
</select>

 <select class="select--two">
   <option value="div-4">Div 4</option>
   <option value="div-5">Div 5</option>
   <option value="div-6">Div 6</option>
</select>

 <select class="select--three">
   <option value="div-7">Div 7</option>
   <option value="div-8">Div 8</option>
   <option value="div-9">Div 9</option>
</select>

<br>

<div id="div-1" class="one active">div 1</div>
<div id="div-2" class="one">div 2</div>
<div id="div-3" class="one">div 3</div>

<div id="div-4" class="two active">div 4</div>
<div id="div-5" class="two">div 5</div>
<div id="div-6" class="two">div 6</div>

<div id="div-7" class="three active">div 7</div>
<div id="div-8" class="three">div 8</div>
<div id="div-9" class="three">div 9</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use one on change function. With the data attr you can select divs for the different select fields.

Hope this helps.

```js
  
        $('select').change(function() {
            var varOrder = $(this).data('order');
            var var1 = $(this).val();
            $('.'+varOrder).removeClass('active');
            $('#' + var1 ).addClass('active');
        });
```

```css
div {
    display: none;
}
div.active{
    display: block;
    margin:40px 40px 0 0;
    background : gold;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;
    float:left;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Show Selected Div </p> 

<select class="select--one" data-order="one">
   <option value="div-1">Div 1</option>
   <option value="div-2">Div 2</option>
   <option value="div-3">Div 3</option>
</select>

 <select class="select--two" data-order="two">
   <option value="div-4">Div 4</option>
   <option value="div-5">Div 5</option>
   <option value="div-6">Div 6</option>
</select>

 <select class="select--three" data-order="three">
   <option value="div-7">Div 7</option>
   <option value="div-8">Div 8</option>
   <option value="div-9">Div 9</option>
</select>

<br>

<div id="div-1" class="one active">div 1</div>
<div id="div-2" class="one">div 2</div>
<div id="div-3" class="one">div 3</div>

<div id="div-4" class="two active">div 4</div>
<div id="div-5" class="two">div 5</div>
<div id="div-6" class="two">div 6</div>

<div id="div-7" class="three active">div 7</div>
<div id="div-8" class="three">div 8</div>
<div id="div-9" class="three">div 9</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do something like this:

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var div = $('option:selected', this).val();
  $('select').not(this).val(0); // reset the other selects but this
  $('div').removeClass('active');
  $('#' + div).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
div.active {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: gold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Show Selected Div</p>

<select>
  <option value="0">select...</option>
  <option selected value="div-1">Div 1</option>
  <option value="div-2">Div 2</option>
  <option value="div-3">Div 3</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="0">select...</option>
  <option value="div-4">Div 4</option>
  <option value="div-5">Div 5</option>
  <option value="div-6">Div 6</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="0">select...</option>
  <option value="div-7">Div 7</option>
  <option value="div-8">Div 8</option>
  <option value="div-9">Div 9</option>
</select>


<div id="div-1" class="active">div 1</div>
<div id="div-2">div 2</div>
<div id="div-3">div 3</div>
<div id="div-4">div 4</div>
<div id="div-5">div 5</div>
<div id="div-6">div 6</div>
<div id="div-7">div 7</div>
<div id="div-8">div 8</div>
<div id="div-9">div 9</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me out with this i was wondering if it's possible to make a function and call it on different div #ID's ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it `this` way:

```
$('.select--one, .select--two, .select--three').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('div').removeClass('active');
    $('#' + val ).addClass('active');
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$('.select--one, .select--two, .select--three').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('div').removeClass('active');
  $('#' + val ).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
div.active{
  display: block;
  margin-top:40px;
  background : gold;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Show Selected Div </p> 

<select class="select--one">
  <option value="div-1">Div 1</option>
  <option value="div-2">Div 2</option>
  <option value="div-3">Div 3</option>
</select>

<select class="select--two">
  <option value="div-4">Div 4</option>
  <option value="div-5">Div 5</option>
  <option value="div-6">Div 6</option>
</select>

<select class="select--three">
  <option value="div-7">Div 7</option>
  <option value="div-8">Div 8</option>
  <option value="div-9">Div 9</option>
</select>


<div id="div-1" class="active">div 1</div>
<div id="div-2">div 2</div>
<div id="div-3">div 3</div>
<div id="div-4">div 4</div>
<div id="div-5">div 5</div>
<div id="div-6">div 6</div>
<div id="div-7">div 7</div>
<div id="div-8">div 8</div>
<div id="div-9">div 9</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me out with this i was wondering if it's possible to make a function and call it on different div #ID's ?

Comment: @VinayKashyap Why do you wanna do that? What exactly you wanna do?